# What does key mean when creating a kubernetes configmap from a file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I see [here](https://github.com/dgkanatsios/CKAD-exercises/blob/master/d.configuration.md#create-and-display-a-configmap-from-a-file-giving-the-key-special) a syntax like this:

```
kubectl create cm configmap4 --from-file=special=config4.txt
```

I did not find a description of what repetition of = and the **special** means here. 
Kubernetes documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files) only denotes one time usage of **=** after **--from-file** while creating configmaps in kubectl.

Answer (score 2):

It appears from generating the YAML that this middle key mean all the keys that are being loaded from the file to be nested inside the mentioned key (special keyword in the question example).

It appears like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  special: |
    var3=val3
    var4=val4
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-06-01T08:20:15Z"
  name: configmap4
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "123320"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/configmap4
  uid: 1582b155-8446-11e9-87b7-0800277f619d
```

Comment: in this case, shall we access this in deployement config as special.var3 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=path/to/bar
```

When creating a configmap based on a file, the key will default to the basename of the file, and the value will default to the file content.  If the basename is an invalid key, you may specify an alternate key.

---

**Create a new configmap named my-config with specified keys instead of file basenames on disk**

```
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=key1=/path/to/bar/file1.txt --from-file=key2=/path/to/bar/file2.txt
```